# Using sed with command line argument?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to run a sed command like this as part of a shell script

```
sed 's/brad/pitt/g'
```

I am supposed to provide brad as a command line argument and run a command like this

```
sed s/$1/pitt/g
```

While this command is working, what I would like to know is how can I do this command without removing the quotes, since I might have some content in the replacement string which needs the quotes.

I am not so confident with the quotes and that is why I want to see how things will work with a little tweaking?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can `sed "s/$1/pitt/g"` or `sed 's/'$1'/pitt/g'`

or, if the command line argument is not a simple word, `sed 's/'"$1"'/pitt/g'`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your second point? How will double quotes help, I mean for what kind of input will be necessary?

Comment: input like `more than one word`. but if it contains special characters (interpreted by sed), it's getting a bit more complicated.

Comment: here's what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern

Comment: i tried with sed -i '' "s/brad/$1/g" but it didn't work. on MacOS

Comment: sed -i s/$1/pitt/g file gives se_f:1: no matches found: s/$1/pitt/g . When using the i flag, you need quotes, either double quotes or single quotes that move around the $params.

Comment: sed 's/'$1'/pitt/g' works on macOS

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can do it:

1) use double quotes

```
 sed "s/$1/pitt/g"
```

2) construct the command as a string and run it with eval

```
SEDCMD="s/$1/pitt/g"
eval sed $SEDCMD
```

The eval method works and is very flexible, but is considered dangerous, because it is vulnerable to code injection. If you don't trust your inputs, don't use #2

UPDATE: The comments are right, there is no benefit to using eval (I used to use eval with sed this way all the time, and I'm not sure why....) building sed strings for later use, however, is powerful: so I'll add a new 3) and leave 2 for folks to mock

3) construct the command as a string and then run 1 or more of them

```
FOO='s/\(.*\)bar/\1baz/'
BAR="s/$1/pitt/g"
sed -e $BAR -e $FOO <infile >outfile
```

Comment: `eval` is a horrible idea with *zero* benefits.

Comment: Don't use #1 either if you don't trust your inputs. It is also amenable to code injection.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `somescript $'.*/echo rm -r .../; w.bashrc.foo\ns/brad'` will write `echo rm -r ...` into `.bashrc.foo`. You can write arbitrary data into arbitrary files by injecting sed code.